# Change the :before selector from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

How to change the :before content of #abc style from javascript ?

```
<script>
document.getElementById('abc').style.content='-';
</script>

<style>
#abc:before{content:"+";}
</style>
```

Comment: Some nice answers are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot access `:before` or `:after` from javascript, because they are not a part of the DOM. However you can still achieve your goal by using CSS classes:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').className = "minus";
</script>

<style>
    #abc:before {content: "+";}
    #abc.minus:before {content: "-"}
</style>
```

In fact this approach is more unobtrusive, because you don't mix representation with javascript. Tomorrow you might want to change text "+/-" to say nice background images, in this case you don't have to touch javascript code at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change the before since it is a pseudo element and not part of the DOM. What you can do is maybe add another class with javascript that has a seperate before specification.

Please see if this question can help you do a work-around [Changing width property of a :before css selector using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery)

Comment: -1 for jQuery related answer on a question without the [tag:jquery] tag.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot set css properties on :before content, since it is not contained in an element. If you want to be able to manipulate the color of the :before content with javascript, you can create an extra css class, and add/remove this class.

Answer (score 0):

So update `#abc` to

```
#abc {
content: attr(data-before);
}
```

and ensure that the element that #abc refers to has a data attribute e.g

Then in your js, you can access the `data-before` attribute using the HTML data API and as you modify that, the content will change too.

Does that make sense?