# Inserting CSS rule via javascript error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'insertRule' ... Failed to parse the rule'

Tags: javascript, css

**EDIT:** This couldn't be a duplicate of [Change the :before selector from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659170) as I'm trying to insert a rule and not to update an existing one. So for anyone searching for the the same problem of insertingRules with this error wont find the suggested duplicate! I didn't and it doesn't necessarily help!
**END EDIT!**

I'm trying to insert a webkit specific rule into a css file through javascript. The rule I am trying to insert is:

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value:after{background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}
```

What the browser doesn't accept is the `:after` selector. Is there another way to target this specific rule including `:after`?

I'm inserting the css this way which works fine for all other rules I have. Its only this one that fails!

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[2], index = 0;

sheet.insertRule('progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value:after{background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}', index);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the :before selector from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659170/change-the-before-selector-from-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't `after` always need `content`?

Comment: @titi23 thanks for the down vote, and no its not the same to update a rule as inserting new ones.

Comment: @torazaburo do you mean that I should add content to the rule I am trying to insert? Tried and didn't help. Other :after rules that I am inserting the same way works fine.