# querySelector ":before"

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create my own `Radio Button`. I have created a `Switch` prototype and I'm not able to select the `:before` of the `this` div.radio_button. How can I query the `:before` into a variable?

```js
HTMLDivElement.prototype.Switch = function() {
  if ((this.getAttribute("class") == "radio_button")) {
    var s = this.querySelector("::before"); // s being null
    console.log(s);
  }
};
HTMLDivElement.prototype.selected = false;

document.querySelector("div.radio_button").Switch();
```

```css
div.radio_button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div.radio_button:before {
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio_button"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22659430/11976387

Comment: Nothing helpful was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you question!
Let's achieve the effect in another way.

```css
div.radio-button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.radio-button::before{
    content: '';
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
div.radio-button.radio-sleep:before {
    left: 0;
}

div.radio-button.radio-active:before {
    left: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 68, 75);
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-button radio-sleep"></div>
```

```
    HTMLDivElement.prototype.switch = function() {
        let classList = this.classList;
        if (classList.contains("radio-button")) {
            if(classList.contains("radio-active")){
                classList.remove("radio-active");
                classList.add("radio-sleep");
            }else{
                classList.add("radio-active");
                classList.remove("radio-sleep");
            }
            this.selected = !this.selected;
        }
    };
    HTMLDivElement.prototype.selected = false;

    let divButton= document.querySelector("div.radio-button");

    divButton.addEventListener("click",e=>{
        divButton.switch();
    });
```

All problems is easy to solve in this way.

Answer (score 0):

edit:
Since you want it to be programmatically you could create a style tag that targets your pseudo selector via css and change the content in that styletag programmatically. Like this for example:

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.Switch = function() {
  if ((this.getAttribute("class") == "radio_button")) {
    addRadioButtonStyle();
  }
};
HTMLDivElement.prototype.selected = false;

document.querySelector("div.radio_button").Switch();

function addRadioButtonStyle() {
    var css = '.radio_button:before {top: 0 }',
        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = document.createElement('style');

    head.appendChild(style);

    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.id = 'radio_button_style';
    if (style.styleSheet){
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
}

function changeRadioButtonTopStyle(val) {
    var styleTag = document.getElementById('radio_button_style');
    var newStyle = '.radio_button:before { top: '+val+'px !important }';
    styleTag.innerText = newStyle;
}

changeRadioButtonTopStyle(50);
```

Comment: I wanted to query the `before`, to edit its value `top`. how to do it?

Comment: Do you need to change it only once or dynamically? If only once (or a few times) you could make one (or multiple) css classes which inherit the style you want and just switch out the classes.

Comment: i will have to change it many times

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to directly set the pseudo element via javascript. 

A workaround if you need this somehow to be programmatic might be to create a styletag that has a class and :before which targets your selector. If you give this tag an id you can query the style tag and change its content (the top value you were mentioning). If you always keep the same class it will update automatically.
It feels a bit overkill though but it's the only thing that comes to my mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through window.getComputedProperty() method. Like in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style>
  h1:before {
    content: "AAA";
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<h1>BBB</h1>

<script>
  let elm = document.querySelector('h1')
  let pseudoElm = getComputedStyle(elm, ':before')

  console.log(pseudoElm.title)
  console.log(pseudoElm.color)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit pseudo element styles using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) ([caniuse?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)) this way:

```js
$('div').css({"--bTop": "50px"});
```

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
div::before {
    content: '---';
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--bTop);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Element</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u85mfp42/1/)

No problem to animate them, too:

```js
$('div').css({"--bTop": "30px"});
$({foo:30}).animate({foo:100}, {
    step: function(val) {
        $('div').css({"--bTop": val+"px"});
    },
 duration: 3000
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  --bTop: 0;
}

div::before {
  content: '---';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--bTop);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Element</div>
```