# CSS ::before ::after pseudo elements dynamic width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I want to make rate stars progress bar with single `div` element and css pseudo elements like `::before`.

Only thing what I can't do is manipulating width of `::before` element with Javascript.

**Here is my example:**

```css
.review-rate {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 width: 100px;
 height: 18px;
}
.review-rate::before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: attr(data-width);
 height: 18px;
 width: 55%;
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: 0 -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="review-rate" data-toggle="review" data-value="3.5" data-width="50" data-count="17"></div>
```

Is there any way to manipulate `width` of `::before` element?

Maybe something like `width: attr(data-width);` ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried the stuff with attr() for width, but you might need to add your units, e.g. `width: attr(data-width)px;`

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: this thread has all the explanations [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way I know of changing `:before` & `:after` css dynamically is the one @Brett DeWoody mentioned, Adding style tags.

In your case you can simply switch the role of `:before` & `div`. Then use div width instead of `:before`. Like this:

```css
.review-rate {
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
background-position: 0 -18px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 18px;
overflow: visible;
position: relative;
width: 50px;
}
.review-rate::before {
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 18px;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="review-rate" data-toggle="review" data-value="3.5" data-width="50" data-count="17"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Though it's not ideal, you can append a new `<style>` element to the page using jQuery with the new `width` value.

```
$('head').append('<style>.review-rate:before{width:75%}</style>');
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/hktt43Ly/).

**Update**
As Imran pointed out in the comment below, the above approach would result in many `<style>` tags over time. To prevent this a combo of `append` and `replaceWith` could be used to keep the number of `<style>` tags to a minimum.

```
if ($('head style[data-class="review-rate"]').length) {
    $('head style[data-class="review-rate"]').replaceWith('<style data-class="review-rate">.review-rate:before{width:75%}</style>')       
} else {
    $('head').append('<style data-class="review-rate">.review-rate:before{width:35%}</style>');
}
```

Comment: True @ImranBughio. Some fancier jQuery could solve this however. For example, instead of using `append` you could use `append` with `replaceWith` to prevent too many style tags. The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/hktt43Ly/) has been updated with an example.

Comment: Just want to note that you don't need jQuery, the DOM API has what you need: `document.head.querySelector`, `parentElement.appendChild` and `parentElement.replaceChild`