# Javascript show and hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make this when I click the header it will hide or show the List? and when its visible the header shows - and when its not visible it shows a +. Thanks a lot

```
 <div class="RevealCard">
  <h3 class="RevealCard-header">
  Top five loves
  </h3>
  <ol class="RevealCard-list">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
RevealCard-header {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.RevealCard-header::after {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "-";
  height: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.15em;
}

.RevealCard-list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to be able to click on "Top five loves" and have the list under it appear/disappear?

Comment: Show us what you have tried until now

Comment: @freginold yeah

Comment: @jcdumdumaya Gotcha. See my solution below.

Comment: So you've got all sorts of options, @jcdumdumaya -- the issue I see here is we still don't know if you'd done any of this work youself, or are we doing schoolwork FOR you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```js
var header = document.getElementsByClassName('RevealCard-header')[0];
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('RevealCard-list')[0];
var collapseChar = document.getElementById('collapseChar');

header.addEventListener('click', function(){
 // toggle list on click
  if (list.style.display.toLowerCase() != "none") {
   // hide list
    list.style.display = "none";
    collapseChar.innerHTML = "&plus;";
  }
  else {
   // show list
    list.style.display = "block";
    collapseChar.innerHTML = "&minus;";    
  }
})
```

```css
RevealCard-header {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.RevealCard-header::after {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "-";
  height: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.15em;
}

.RevealCard-list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#collapseChar {
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="RevealCard">
  <h3 class="RevealCard-header">
  <span id="collapseChar">&minus;</span>Top five loves
  </h3>
  <ol class="RevealCard-list">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

You just have to check to see if the list is visible.  If it's not, show it; if it is, hide it.

It's also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/freginold/tqd8bd5d/) as a fiddle, if you want to play around with it.

Comment: Not really a fan of the semantically meaningless collapseChar, but it's a good workaround.

Comment: @Snowmonkey Me neither, but I couldn't think of a better name off the top of my head.

Comment: Nice. How do I do it if I have another with the same div?

Comment: @jcdumdumaya Do you mean another header, or another list? If you're using multiple collapsible lists, you'd probably want to create a function and pass the list reference in as a parameter.

Comment: @freginold I have 2 sets of that Reveal Card. How do i make both work? I tried doing it myself but it won't work

Comment: @jcdumdumaya You just have to target them individually. As an example, assign the second header to a variable like this: `var header2 = document.getElementsByClassName('RevealCard-header')[1];`. Do the same thing for the list -- call it `list2` (or something else) and grab the 2nd item in the list class (`RevealCard-list`) which would actually be `[1]` since it starts counting from 0.

Comment: @jcdumdumaya That looks more confusing than it sounded in my head.  If you can't get it to work over the weekend, shoot me a comment on here and I'll add a second list to the example, unless someone else can do it sooner.

Comment: @jcdumdumaya, Take a look at mine, below. It was a matter of how I accessed the DOM structure of each RevealCard, but the changes were trivial.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much man. I'm kinda new to javascript so I am not used to using eventlistener

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
function clickDropdown(){

  var listitems = document.getElementById("RevealCard");
  var header = document.getElementById("RevealCard-header").innerHTML;
  
  if(listitems.style.display == "none"){
    listitems.style.display = 'block';
    
    header = header.replace('+', '-');
  document.getElementById("RevealCard-header").innerHTML = header;
  }else{
    listitems.style.display = 'none';
    header = header.replace('-','+');
    document.getElementById("RevealCard-header").innerHTML = header;
  }

}
```

```css
RevealCard-header {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.RevealCard-header::after {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "-";
  height: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.15em;
}

.RevealCard-list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="RevealCard">
<a onClick="clickDropdown()">  <h3 id="RevealCard-header">
  Top five loves +
  </h3></a>
  <ol style="display: none;" id="RevealCard">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

Comment: Close. Still need to toggle the + / - in the h3's pseudo style.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you want to toggle the OL element, you also want to change the pseudo ::after css. Easiest way? Create a second css ::after style, and simply toggle them both. See below.

```js
var myHead = document.getElementsByClassName("RevealCard-header");
for (var i = 0, j = myHead.length; i  < j; i++) {
  myHead[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var myTab = this.parentNode.querySelector("ol");

    if (myTab.style.display == "") {
      // Because of the pseudo ::after el, we'll
      //  create a showing/hiding class.
      this.classList.remove("header-showing");
      this.classList.add("header-hiding");
      myTab.style.display = "none"
    } else {
      this.classList.remove("header-hiding");
      this.classList.add("header-showing");
      myTab.style.display = "";
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.RevealCard {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.RevealCard-header {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.header-showing::after {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "-";
  height: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.15em;
}

.header-hiding::after {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "+";
  height: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.15em;
}

.RevealCard-list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="RevealCard">
  <h3 class="RevealCard-header header-showing">
    Top five loves
  </h3>
  <ol class="RevealCard-list">
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>Fourth item</li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="RevealCard">
  <h3 class="RevealCard-header header-showing">
    Another five loves
  </h3>
  <ol class="RevealCard-list">
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>Fourth item</li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Updated to support multiple sets. You do this by attaching the listener to the head, then working within its own parent's DOM structure.

Comment: I like how you used `::after`.

Comment: Honestly, wasn't sure I could simply change the ::after's content, so it was a quick hack to create a second class. Can the pseudo-element content be edited via javascript?

Comment: Seems the consensus is no, because they are not actually part of the DOM, but there are some workarounds here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Hacky. I think my solution is pretty simple, I guess I'll run with it. He. Thanks, though, @freginold.