# How to change #new-quote:before background using JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know how to change the background of the #new-quote:before element because using information in this thread: [Changing width property of a :before css selector using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery/16507264#16507264), I've learned we can only do it using special techniques and only content property of CSS. But what about other properties of CSS, like the background?

```
 colors = [
  "#ff9966",
  "#7f00ff",
  "#396afc",
  "#0cebeb",
  "#06beb6",
  "#642b73",
  "#36d1dc",
  "#cb356b",
  "#3a1c71",
  "#ef3b36",
  "#159957",
  "#000046",
  "#007991",
  "#56ccf2",
  "#f2994a",
  "#e44d26",
  "#4ac29a",
  "#f7971e",
  "#34e89e",
  "#6190e8",
  "#3494e6",
  "#ee0979"
],
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
```

What I've used for my project is:

```
var addRule = function(sheet, selector, styles) {
if (sheet.insertRule) 
  return sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + styles + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
if (sheet.addRule)
  return sheet.addRule(selector, styles);
}

addRule(document.styleSheets[0], "#new-quote:before", "content: colors[randomNumber]");
```

So yeah, it works with the content property, but what about the background one?

```
addRule(document.styleSheets[0], "#new-quote:before", "content: colors[randomNumber]");
```

Nope :( Here is my codepen for full project code:

See the Pen [xpgBNv](https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/xpgBNv/) by Lukas ([@Kestis500](https://codepen.io/Kestis500)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

---

This line of code fixed everything! :)

```
$('head').append("<style>#new-quote:before{background:"+ colors[randomNumber] + ";}</style>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a style tag with your custom css color and append it to head

**See Example**

```js
colors = [
  "#ff9966",
  "#7f00ff",
  "#396afc",
  "#0cebeb",
  "#06beb6",
  "#642b73",
  "#36d1dc",
  "#cb356b",
  "#3a1c71",
  "#ef3b36",
  "#159957",
  "#000046",
  "#007991",
  "#56ccf2",
  "#f2994a",
  "#e44d26",
  "#4ac29a",
  "#f7971e",
  "#34e89e",
  "#6190e8",
  "#3494e6",
  "#ee0979"
],
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
$('head').append("<style>.div1:before{background:"+ colors[randomNumber] + "}</style>");
```

```css
.div1:before {
  content: 'before  ';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">container2</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote not a correct question. What I need is to set a random background color from the colors[] array. Let me fix it.

Comment: I've edited my question. The background color should be random and not static like red in the css.