# Get Margin Value of :after selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with a custom slider, I have many slide indicators. There should be an orange color line between 2 indicators e.g If I click on indicator 1 then there will be the line between indicators 1 and 2 and if I click indicator 2 then there will be line between 2 and 3 and so on.
For this line, I'm using :after selector.
**CSS Code:**

```
.carousel-indicators li:after{
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background: orange;
    top: 28%;
    left: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML code:-**

```
 <!-- Carousel Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
<!-- Carousel Indicators End -->
```

I've calculated that if we move from indicator 1 to nth indicator then I need to add a 6% margin in left. I want to do this with the help of jQuery i.e if I move from indicator 1 to nth then I'll add %6 in the previous margin-left (1+6 = 7%) similarly if I move from 2 to 3 then I'll add %6 in previous margin-left (7+6 = 13%) and so on. But here I need to get the previous margin-left so that I can perform some calculation/addition. How can I get :after selector margin-left?
I tried the following code but it's giving me undefined.

```
$('.carousel-indicators li').click( function (){
        margLeft = $('.carousel-indicators li:after').css('margin-left');
        console.log(margLeft);
    });
```

and

```
$('.carousel-indicators li').click( function (){
        margLeft = $('.carousel-indicators li:after').css('marginLeft');
        console.log(margLeft);
    });
```

Bot are giving output as undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

To get margin of after element by use **`getPropertyValue()`** with **`getComputedStyle()`**

### About `getComputedStyle()`

> The **[`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

### About `getPropertyValue()`

> The **[`CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)** method interface returns a DOMString containing the value of a specified CSS property.

```
window.getComputedStyle(this, ':after').getPropertyValue('margin-left');
```

### You are not given margin-left to `.carousel-indicators li:after` so it gets **0px**.

```js
$('.carousel-indicators li').click( function (){
    var marginLeft = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':after').getPropertyValue('margin-left');
    console.log(marginLeft)
});
```

```css
.carousel-indicators li:after{
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  top: 28%;
  left: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Carousel Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
<!-- Carousel Indicators End -->
```

### I added `margin-left:20px`

```
.carousel-indicators li:after{
  margin-left:20px
}
```

```js
$('.carousel-indicators li').click( function (){
    var marginLeft = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':after').getPropertyValue('margin-left');
    console.log(marginLeft)
});
```

```css
.carousel-indicators li:after{
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  top: 28%;
  left: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:20px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Carousel Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
<!-- Carousel Indicators End -->
```

Comment: Are you want something like this @Ali Bhutta? if any changes i would be happy to change the answer too. By the way Thanks :) :D.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it's giving me 0px as output :'(

Comment: upvote for your effort. hope this will encourage you :)

Comment: btw thanks :) @Ali Bhutta

Comment: same 2 you, I embedded  HTML code also in my question hope you may tell me why I'm still getting 0px

Comment: i updated answer. you not given margin-left so it get 0px. if you add any value to margin-left it gets :)

Comment: left: 1% is margin left.